# Why EF generating a sub-query for a simle query?

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework

There is a simple Linq to EF:

```
var query = from p in _db.Posts
            where p.BlogtId == blogId
            select p;
```

It generates SQL in this form:

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`PostId`, 
`Extent1`.`BlogId`, 
...
FROM `Posts` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`BlogId` = @p__linq__0
```

But when I add a order by to this query

```
var query = from p in _db.Posts
            where p.BlogId == blogId
            orderby p.PublishDate
            select p;
```

It generates this query

```
SELECT
`Project1`.`PostId`, 
`Project1`.`BlogId`, 
...
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`PostId`, 
`Extent1`.`BlogId`, 
...
FROM `Posts` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`BlogId` = @p__linq__0) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`PublishDate` ASC
```

Why this generate a sub-query?There is a performance problem for this query in MySQL. MySQL is trying to execute the inner query which pulls back all the records in the database and then tries to sort theme.

I need a solution to generate below sql by linq

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`PostId`, 
...
FROM `Posts` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`BlogId` = @p__linq__0
 ORDER BY 
`Extent1`.`PublishDate` ASC
```

Comment: What difference does it make to you?

Comment: @podiluska There is a performance problem for this query in MySQL. MySQL is trying to execute the inner query which pulls back all the records in the database and then tries to sort theme.

Comment: Why would it pull them all back - they're filtered?

Comment: I don't see how this should be any slower than the query you suggest. The EF version is awkward to read, I'll admit. It's very explicitly filtering in the sub-query and then ordering the final result set. Maybe this is LINQ's way of making sure the RDBMS doesn't sort all results before filtering? Are you indexes set up correctly? How about some performance metrics of each query?

Comment: EF doesn't generate SQL. It generates an ADO.NET CCT. Your MySQL provider generates the SQL. Ask the author of the provider why it generates SQL which MySQL doesn't handle well.

Comment: @CraigStuntz please read this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/4f226e7a-66de-4878-93b3-7cb397c4ad5d/ Q:One more question, this problem is related with MySql Data provider or it comes from the Core of EntityFramework/Linq to entities?  A:This is related to EF, if possible, I suggest you to upgrade the version in the future, the newest version will be more effective. :)

Comment: @podiluska there is over 30000 row for this filter

Comment: @GhootiFarangi: I'll repeat: EF doesn't generate SQL; your MySQL provider does. EF doesn't know anything about MySQL's SQL syntax. That comes from the provider. I see that a MS person kind of sort of implied otherwise, but that doesn't make it true.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an entity-framework issue, despite what your link might tell others. It is in relation to the MySqlConnector/net. I can prove it! Ah, didn't expect that huh.

Hook this exact scenario up using a MSSQL database, with the `System.Data` connector, and you will see properly formed SQL. This is an issue with projections inside of MySqlConnector. If you want to fix it, then go in and edit it yourself.

Here is how to have a locally edited copy of MySqlConnector/net: [How to customize MySql Connector/net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12944570/1026459)